# The attribute of echarts radiusAxis.splitLine.show

Tags: echarts

The document said: whether to display a separator line. The default value axis is displayed, but the category axis is not.
Why the category is not display? Is there a way to show it?

Comment: [Demo of the chart](https://jsfiddle.net/creadone/rLea6mxu/) with the code significantly increases the probability and speed of detailed answer. No one has time to guess what mistake you might have made out of hundreds possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example:

```js
var options = {
  // [...]
  radiusAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    axisLabel: {
      interval: 0
    } 
  // [...]
}
```